# Android Extra line shows OpenGL GL_Line

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have the following...

```
GLfloat test[8] = {-0.3f,-0.4f,0.3f,0.4f,0.2f,-0.4f,-0.2f,0.4f};
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, test);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 8);
```

The problem is when it is rendered it looks like this...

[image]

Can anyone help me with what I am missing? I am fairly new to OpenGL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops I found it...

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 8);
```

The 8 here I thought was the number of entries in the array but it is actually the number of vectors (2 points per vector). So dividing the 8 by 2 (4) gives the expected results.